# Tapestry: Mixin Autocomple​te pop-up floats up and down the page with webpage scrollbar

Tags: css, autocomplete, tapestry

I have a autocomplete mixin. When the list of suggestions pop-up, it doesn't stay put in one place. If you scroll down the webpage, it will float down. If you scroll up, it will float up. I want it to stay at my TextField where the Autocomplete mixin is at.

Here is my tml file

```
<input t:type="TextField" t:id="emailUpdate" t:mixins="autocomplete" value="email"/>
```

Comment: this is too little info to go by. Like previous questions, please provide an example on jsfiddle and let us know what browser you are using. This is most likely related to css that needs some investigation. I think there will be a position:fixed; somewhere where it does not belong but no way of telling without an example. PS: I use the autocomplete without a problem.

Comment: Default behaviour is that it stays at the TextField. So it must be as @joostschouten said, something in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should set in css

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: relative;
}
```